# kohana 3.1 ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method upload::valid()

Tags: upload, kohana

im try to use kohana 3.1 upload. But i get the above error. im using the example [here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/image/examples/upload)

Ok i have looked for the error around the net and i cant get where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had put a vendor directory in my DOCROOT and place this in my bootstrap file

require_once(APPPATH.'vendor/upload/upload.php');

So kohana was looking for the upload class here instead of in the system.

Thanks alot [zeebee](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/profile/3439/zeebee) for your solution.

I used the first one and automatically saw the error. 
the upload class is now working perfectly...